# Is there a || operator for int?

Tags: java, int, boolean, operators

I am trying to write a method that takes a single int parameter that is the numeric month and returns the number of days in the given month. So, a parameter of 1 would return 31 since there are 31 days in January and a parameter of 2 would return 28 since there are 28 days in February.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 public static void daysInMonth(int month) {
           if (month == 1||3||5||7||8||10||12)
         System.out.println("31");
      else if (month == 4||6||9||11)
         System.out.println("30");
      else if (month == 2)
         System.out.println("28");
```

I keep getting the error message "operator || cannot be applied to boolean,int." Can anyone help me figure out what to do?

Comment: Are you looking for Bitwise operators or looking for month==1 || month==2

Comment: the prompt specifically says that implementation should use logical ops (&& or ||) and not use twelve if / else if / else blocks.

Comment: Isiaiah, I used that second option of yours and i no longer get an error message within the static method, but when I try to call the static method in the main method, I get the error message "'void' type not allowed here."

Comment: The return type is not void. There is something wrong with your code.

Comment: Let me add what I have to the question, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Sure, if you un-downvote my answer.

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst:  The OP doesn't even *remotely* have enough rep to have downvoted your post.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to introduce new state or ask a new question.  By doing so you would've invalidated all previous and existing answers.

Comment: I just joined, when I tried to upvote it I got a message telling me I needed more reputation to upvote anything

Comment: If you're going to use that "or" method, just call it like if(or(month, 1, 3, 5)) { System.out.println("31"); }

Comment: Makoto, should I go ahead and change it back and just ask a new question?

Comment: Is the new question you're asking going to be the same as above (that is, you're getting the same error), or is it going to be asking something different (you're now getting an error with a new way of building the expression out)?  By the way, use @ to refer to a person by name - you can type @Makoto and it will ping me directly, if I'm watching this topic or not.  But, note that only works if I've commented on something, so you won't be able to ping anyone that hasn't commented here.

Comment: Why on earth was this reopened?

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this:

```
if ( (month == 1) || (month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7)
                  || (month ==  8) || (month == 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid any switch or if/else statements with the new Java 1.8 time API using [`java.time.Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html):

```
public static int daysInMonth(int month) {
    return Month.of(month).minLength();
}
```

Comment: `void` and `return` ?  and you are probably looking for `maxLength()`, how does it deal with (leap) year  ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi oops, copy&paste error from the code in the question, thanks. I've used `minLength()` because the example explicitly states February should be 28 days. If you want to take leap years into account, `length(boolean leapYear)` would be the better choice

Answer (score 1):

You can use the || operator on a boolean expression :

```
if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5) {
    // do something ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`||` will result into `boolean` and then `boolean` || `int` is not valid action

what you need is

```
month == 1 || month == 3 || ...
```

or a `Map<Integer, Integer> monthNumberToMaxDaysMap`

also this way you don't have leap year scenario covered, it is suitable to re-use already solved problem

```
 public static void daysInMonth(int month) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month -1);
    return cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
 }
```

above method only considers current year, you could leverage it to pass year as well